# How to backup and restore a web application and/or site collection

Tags: backup, restore

I am trying to find the best way to accomplish the following:
Move an existing share point application's content and meta databases, back them up and restore them to a different machine.
In order to do this I am using the stsadm tool as follows:
To backup, I use this command:

> stsadm -o backup -url http://devpn-004:1234 -directory c:\sharePointBackup -filename testBackup.bak -backupmethod full -percentage 10

To restore, I use this command:

> stsadm -o restore -url %1 -directory c:\sharePointBackup -restoremethod overwrite -percentage 10

The backup completes successfully. However, when I try to restore, I get the following errors:

> Provisioning of the web application, SharePoint - 1234, has encountered the following error: 
>    System.ArgumentException: The IIS Web Site you have selected is in use by SharePoint.
>    You must select another port or hostname.
>
> Object MySharepointDB1234 failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the error log located in the backup directory.
>    SqlException: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

The machine on which the restore takes place already has an existing web application at the port specified, and since the overwrite flag is used, I would expect no errors.
I would appreciate any help and insight on the best practice to backup from machine a and restore to machine b a complete application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use stsadm -o export and import options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provision the application before doing a restore?  I would provision a test site collection to validate that the application is working before trying to restore a site collection to it.

I'm not familiar with the %1 for the URL, you may want to specify the actual url.

Comment: Mike,
The site is successfully provisioned and up. The %1 character is my batch file artifact. It is replaced with an actual http://myrul:1234 even when run with these parameters, I still get the "Used by sharepoint error".